# ORMLite foreign field null on create, not null on query

Tags: android, ormlite

When writing an instance of my data class to the database via ORMLite, and one of the child members (a foreign field) is null, I get back a non null child member.

Data classes as follows:

```
public class Site {
    //  snip
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = true)
    private InstallationType installationType;
}

public class InstallationType {   
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String name;
}
```

When I read my instance of the Site class again via

```
getSiteDao().queryForId(id);
```

the installationType member is non null, but with a non-existent id.  The only way the rest of our application can now work with this object, is if I manually do a lookup through the InstallationTypeDAO and set what I get back on the site. Query will sometimes return null as per [the documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryForId%28ID%29).

Is there a way of getting ORMLite to set this member to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *was* a bug in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) that was fixed in version 4.15 (3/7/2011).  Here's the [change log file](http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt). What version are you using?  Have you tried to update?  Here's the [bug report page](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3199649&group_id=297653&atid=1255989):

Currently the following test passes so I think we have good coverage on that bug.

```
@Test
public void testForeignNull() throws Exception {
    Dao<Foreign, Integer> dao = createDao(Foreign.class, true);
    Foreign foreign = new Foreign();
    foreign.foo = null;
    assertEquals(1, dao.create(foreign));
    Foreign foreign2 = dao.queryForId(foreign.id);
    assertNotNull(foreign2);
    assertNull(foreign2.foo);
}
```

With `Foreign` having the following fields:

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
public int id;
@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
public Foo foo;
```

If you are up to date in versions, please let me know if you can change the test to get it to fail.

Comment: I am using 4.30.  (The version that was packaged with the HelloAndroidNoBase example.)  Will try 4.35 now.

Comment: Upgrading to 4.35 fixed the problem. Thanks Gray.